# Laurent Series and Residues

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, laurent-series

Write the Laurent series expansion of the function $f(z) = \frac {cos(z^2)}{z^7}$
in $0 < |z| < ∞$. Find the residue of this function at 0.

As in my previous question, I am not entirely sure how to find Laurent series expansions. My professor, while very intelligent, has a hard time teaching in a way that is understandable for students.

Comment: If $\displaystyle g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^k$ then $\displaystyle\frac{g(z)}{z^7} = \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k z^{k-7}=\sum_{k=-7}^\infty c_{k+7} z^k$

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\cos z^2}{z^7}=\frac1{z^7}\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n\frac{z^{4n}}{(2n)!}=\frac1{z^7}\left(1-\frac{z^4}2+\frac{z^8}{24}-\ldots\right)$$

and with this you already have the order of the pole $\;z=0\;$ and the function's residue at it.

Comment: What makes this different than the Taylor series expansion?

Comment: It has negative exponents on z

Comment: @MPaul Whose Taylor expansion? I used the cosine's, and mathstackuser also pointed out an obvious difference between power series and Laurent ones.

Comment: How am I able to find the residue?

Comment: @MPaul Just calculate the coefficient of $\;z^{-1}\;$ , of course...how else?

Comment: There is no z^-1

Comment: @MPaul If you're studying this stuff it should be obvious to you **already** that there is not such a thing as " there is no $\;z^{-1}\;$" , which is just like saying that "there is no $\;x\;$ in $\;x^2+1\;$ " ...  This is medium/advanced stuff in undergraduate mathematics.